# How to put image in HashMap by giving a specific url

Tags: java, android

```
private static final String picpic = "picpic";

private ArrayList < HashMap < String, Object>> myBooks;

myBooks = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

 HashMap < String, Object> hm;

hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();

drawable=LoadImage("http://www.wauhaha.com/smart/company/album/pic.jpg");

hm.put(picpic, drawable);


myBooks.add(hm);

 final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myBooks, R.layout.listbox, new String[]{picpic}, new int[]{R.id.image1});


listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: kindly help me ~~ thanks in advance ^^

Comment: What you want actually ? I think listview with Image in your app?

Comment: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_C5a2qH8Y_jk/TBQFC3VNHBI/AAAAAAAAAcs/t7bAWJzD2iY/s1600/AndroidList_02.png

i want somethings like the above url shown ~~~but i want to put image by using URL ,not R.drawable.launcher somethings like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this Example Listview With Custom Adapter.....And see `CustomizedListView`  Activity

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Key to be Url then use this code.

```
//Declarations

public Map<String, Object> ImageMap = new WeakHashMap<String, Object>();

//Inserting into HashMap

public void addToHash(String url)
{
    ImageMap.put(url,LoadImage(url));
}

// Get from HashMap
public Object getImageFromHash(String url)
{
    ImageMap.get(url);
}
```

EDITED
You can use the Solution given by Samir, 
you need to use ImageLoader.java, ImageCache.java, FileCache.java and Utils.java

For your adapter

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> urls;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> u) {
        activity = a;
        urls=u;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listbox, null);

        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(your.imageview.id); // thumb image

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(urls.get(position), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myBooks, R.layout.listbox, new String[]{picpic}, new int[]{R.id.image1});

*how i declare the adapter, coz i try your solution, and doesn't take effect , i still cant get image~~~

Comment: Use can use the solution of samir see my Edited Answer